# How to give Space between Linear Layouts in android

Tags: android

Hi i am beginner in android and i am trying to give space between Linear-layouts as like below image for this i wrote some code but that's not working please help me

My intention is I want to give "20dp" space between every-layout as like below image

### my code:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="data1"
            android:background="#77ff3f" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:text="data2"
            android:background="#ff200f" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:text="data3"
            android:background="#2c23ff"></TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: The simplest way might be to give them all `layout_margin="10dp"` attributes. Also, if the LinearLayouts are only going to have the one TextView child each, then you don't need the LinearLayouts, just the TextViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don not need to wrap you `text-views` into linear layouts.
I would make the top layout linear too and a second for `data1` and `data2`

Using `layout_weights` and the `space-view` can now give you a nice and easy modifyable result.

Like that:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:background="#77ff3f"
            android:text="data1" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:background="#ff200f"
            android:text="data2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#2c23ff"
            android:text="data3"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
If you use `weight` always set the weighted length to `0dp`.

Comment: Hi Altoyr my requirement is i want to take three liniar layouts first linear layout is Vertical layout and second one is Horizental layouts and third one i mean below layout is Vertical layout but in your answer you just take two linear layouts

Comment: please tell me how to give space between first two linear layouts

Comment: Why would you use more layouts than you need? You do not have to put every `TextView` into a single `LinearLayout`. `Layouts` are for grouping multiple `views` (e.g. Buttons, TextViews, EditTexts...) together. And as you can see i am using `Space` to create the space between the layouts.

Comment: ok thanks but want to know how to do same above operation programatically in MainActivity class instaed of .xml can you please explain me that

Comment: There is enough stuff to read about adding Views and Layouts programmatically. Inform yourself first, then ask a new Question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#77ff3f"
            android:text="data1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff200f"
            android:text="data2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#2c23ff"
        android:text="data3" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you explain how to do above operation programatically in MainActivity.java class instead of .xml